# JQuery missing ) after argument list error in this code:

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where is the bug?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hidden").hover(
  function(){
   $("#menu>div#serie>div").show(slide("direction","bottom")400ms);
  },
  function(){
   $("#menu>div#serie>div").hide(slide("direction","top")400ms);
  }
  );
 
});
```

```css
#menu
{
 margin-top:-10px;
  margin-left:-10px;
width:100%;
height:150px;
background-color:#333;
position:fixed;
}
#menu>div
{
line-height:130px;
float:right;
background-color:none;

}
#menu>div>a
{
display:block;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:30px;
color:#2ba8f0;
font-family:arial;
text-decoration:none;
transition:color 400ms ease;
}
#menu>div#serie
{
 width:140px;
height:140px;
background-color:none;
color:#2ba8f0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:130px;
font-family:arial;
background-image:url(images/arrow.svg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;

transition:color 400ms ease;

}

#menu>div#serie>a
{
padding:30px;
}
#menu>div>a:hover
{
color:white;

}


#menu>div#serie:hover
{
height:auto;
background-color:none;
color:white;


}


#menu>div#serie>div>div
{
height:100px; 
}
#menu>div#serie>div>div>a#dropdown
{
 width:140px;
 display:block;
 color:2ba8f0;
 line-height:120px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:#333;
 -webkit-transition:background-color 400ms ease;
 
}
#menu>div#serie>div>div>a#dropdown:hover
{
 background-color:#555;
 color:white;
}
.logo
{
 display:block;
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background-image:url(images/logo.svg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 float:left;
}
#menu>div#serie>div
{
 height:400px;
 margin-top:-25px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <header id="menu">
 
 <div>
        <a href="#"><b>Kontakt</b></a>
      </div>
         
      <div>
        <a href="#"><b>FAQ</b></a>
      </div>
       <div class="serie" id="serie">
           <h4 id="hidden">Postery</h4>
     <div id="hidden" class="hidden">
   <div>
   <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Pre Fanúšikov</b></a>
   </div>
   <div>
   <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Osobné</b></a>
   </div>
   <div>
   <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Chceš jeden?</b></a>
  </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="serie" id="serie">
      
        <h4 id="hidden">Série</h4>
  <div id="hidden" class="hidden">
  <div>
   <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Minecraft</b></a>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Vlogy</b></a>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Ostatné</b></a>
  </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"><b>O mne</b></a>
      </div>
       <div>
      <a href="#"><b>Domov</b></a>
      </div>
     <a class="logo" href="#">
  </a>
  </header>
```

```
    <div>
        <a href="#"><b>Kontakt</b></a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="#"><b>FAQ</b></a>
      </div>
       <div class="serie" id="serie">
           <h4 id="hidden">Postery</h4>
           <div id="hidden" class="hidden">
            <div>
            <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Pre Fanúšikov</b></a>
            </div>
            <div>
            <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Osobné</b></a>
            </div>
            <div>
            <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Chceš jeden?</b></a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="serie" id="serie">

        <h4 id="hidden">Série</h4>
        <div id="hidden" class="hidden">
        <div>
            <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Minecraft</b></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Vlogy</b></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a id="dropdown" href="#"><b>Ostatné</b></a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"><b>O mne</b></a>
      </div>
       <div>
      <a href="#"><b>Domov</b></a>
      </div>
     <a class="logo" href="#">
  </a>
  </header>


#menu
{
    margin-top:-10px;
        margin-left:-10px;
width:100%;
height:150px;
background-color:#333;
position:fixed;
}
#menu>div
{
line-height:130px;
float:right;
background-color:none;

}
#menu>div>a
{
display:block;
padding-right:30px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:30px;
color:#2ba8f0;
font-family:arial;
text-decoration:none;
transition:color 400ms ease;
}
#menu>div#serie
{
    width:140px;
height:140px;
background-color:none;
color:#2ba8f0;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:130px;
font-family:arial;
background-image:url(images/arrow.svg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;

transition:color 400ms ease;

}

#menu>div#serie>a
{
padding:30px;
}
#menu>div>a:hover
{
color:white;

}


#menu>div#serie:hover
{
height:auto;
background-color:none;
color:white;


}


#menu>div#serie>div>div
{
height:100px;   
}
#menu>div#serie>div>div>a#dropdown
{
    width:140px;
    display:block;
    color:2ba8f0;
    line-height:120px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#333;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 400ms ease;

}
#menu>div#serie>div>div>a#dropdown:hover
{
    background-color:#555;
    color:white;
}
.logo
{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-image:url(images/logo.svg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
}
#menu>div#serie>div
{
    height:400px;
    margin-top:-25px;
        display:none;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hidden").hover(
        function(){
            $("#menu>div#serie>div").show(slide("direction","bottom")400ms);
        },
        function(){
            $("#menu>div#serie>div").hide(slide("direction","top")400ms);
        }
        );

});
```

Can you help me?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your `show`, `hide` calls are causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Near "400ms". Twice.

```
$("#menu>div#serie>div").show(slide("direction","bottom")400ms);
```

Should be something like

```
$("#menu>div#serie>div").show(slide("direction","bottom"), "400");
```